# Import Facebook users into AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm new to AWS Cognito, so I may be approaching this wrongly, but fundamentally I want to import users into a Cognito user pool from Facebook.  So users would pay for access to my web application, and then I'd like to import them into my user pool as a valid user, from Facebook.

So my question is: how do I import them from Facebook?  How do I tell AWS that I'd like to add the user to my pool who has a Facebook ID of XYZ?

And yes, I do realize this limits my users to those with Facebook accounts, but for my use case this is absolutely acceptable. I also realize how manual and un-scalable this is, but that, too, is acceptable for my particular use case.

Comment: Creating Userpool users from FB login is not the purpose in authenticating FB with Cognito. For this flow you need to write a API backend to create the userpool user after successful FB authentication validating the FB token at the backend.

Comment: There must be some way to have users social login tied to user cognito pool. If you just post a user to userpool after fb login, you could create cognito user pool user with federated identity id and then could you generate a  successful login to cognito user pool for that user when they return with the same social login?

Answer (score 1):

It's been 4 years since this question was made, so I guess my reply would only help someone else like me that had the same question. And for

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to import a Facebook, Google, or any other Federated Identity Provider, but I found a tricky way to achieve the same result, but not exactly importing, and it would be combining two of Cognito's API: [AdminCreateUser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminCreateUser.html) and [AdminLinkProviderForUser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminLinkProviderForUser.html). So the main idea is: Create a "Cognito User holder" and link its Facebook User to this Cognito User.

Some drawback that I can wander about for this solution is that depending on your option for the Cognito Pool username and required fields you would end up needing to fake those values in order to be able to create the "Cognito User holder". Also, creating the user in this way (using the AdminCreateUser API and faking data) you might need to "manually" confirm the User with the API [AdminConfirmSignUp](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminConfirmSignUp.html), set a permanent password with the API [AdminSetUserPassword](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminSetUserPassword.html) and autoConfirm the email using a [Pre sign-up Lambda trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-sign-up.html)

A stub code based on Java to illustrate the idea would be:

```
 val adminCreateUserResponse = cognitoClient.adminCreateUser(
        AdminCreateUserRequest
            .builder()
            .userPoolId($poolId)
            .username($fakeEmailBasedOnSocialProviderAndSocialProviderId)
            .messageAction("SUPPRESS")
            .build()
    )
    cognitoClient.adminLinkProviderForUser(
        AdminLinkProviderForUserRequest.builder()
            .userPoolId($poolId)
            .sourceUser(
                ProviderUserIdentifierType.builder()
                .providerName($socialProvider)
                .providerAttributeName("Cognito_Subject")
                .providerAttributeValue($socialProviderId).build())
            .destinationUser(
                ProviderUserIdentifierType.builder()
                .providerName("Cognito")
                .providerAttributeValue($adminCreateUserResponse.user().username())
                .build())
        .build())
```

I could validate this theory, and I could successfully authenticate the user using my Facebook account.

Comment: But I would ask "Do you really need to import the user into Cognito Pool?" or letting the user SignUp via Facebook again would be fine?
I ask that because when the User signUp via Facebook, his "sub" field on Congito will be "Facebook_${FacebookId}". And in my case, my backend uses this field to bind the Cognito's User to my its user, I'm just importing my "Backend User" record with the "cognitoUserSub" equals to the "Facebook_${FacebookId}" and waiting for the User SignUp over Facebook again, so once I get his access_token I will match the access_token "sub" with my Backend User record